# What does a horse need to carry your things?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I noticed that you can buy saddlebags that can store up to 20lbs.  Can you put more than 1 set of saddlebags on a horse?  What other options are there for a horse to carry loot?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the entry:

> SADDLEBAGS
>   Price 4 gp; Weight 8 lbs.
>   These sturdy, weatherproof bags **are draped over a saddle** to add extra carrying capacity. Each side of a saddlebag can typically carry 20 pound of items that can fit in the bags. Saddlebags do not increase the amount of weight a mount can carry; they merely give riders a place to stow their equipment. [Source (PRD)](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateEquipment/gear/animalsAndTransports.html)

The RAW for saddlebags states that they "...do not increase the amount of weight a mount can carry." The saddlebags themselves weight 8 lbs. and can hold up to 20 lbs. worth of *loot* on either side. This means that, at max., a saddlebag can weigh as much as 48 lbs. Also take notice of the bolded text (my emphasis). You drape saddlebags over a saddle, and a horse can only wear one saddle. ***This means one set of saddlebags***.

In terms of other options, you also have the pack saddle:

> Pack Saddle: A pack saddle holds gear and supplies, but not a rider. It holds as much gear as the mount can carry. [Source (PRD)](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateEquipment/gear/animalsAndTransports.html)

**Now down to the nitty gritty of the answer:**

A [light horse](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/horse) has a strength of 16, and a [heavy horse](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/horse/heavy-horse) has a strength of 20. This means that they have a maximum carry load of 690 lbs and 1200 lbs., respectively*. But be careful of [encumberance](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/alignment-description/carrying-capacity); this includes your weight if you're riding it!

You also have the various [land vehicles, including wagons](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/vehicles/land-vehicles).

As a further option perhaps you could convince your GM to allow you to use a Handy Haversack as a sort of *Saddlebag of Holding*? Or simply create one yourself using Craft Wondrous Items.

*: Horses are large quadrupeds and receive a multiplier on their carry capacity accordingly.

Comment: Very insightful!  Thank you.  I take it that with wagons and carts the maximum a horse could upll would be determined just like a PC's drag speed?

Comment: Good find. As far as I know, we always ignored those limitations in our Kingmaker campaign. And still we found horses impractical because of all the feed we should carry around. We ended up needing an extra horse to carry the feed for the horses that carried us and our stuff.

Comment: @Nerevar Actually those are two seperate statistics. The maximum load of a (medium) wagon is 2000 lbs. But it still only requires 4 medium creatures or 1 large creature (read: a horse) to pull. Its speed is dependant on the horse, but not the horse's strength. A med. wagon moves at "twice the speed of the pulling creature(s)." Oddly enough the weight of the wagon and the str. of the horse don't factor into its movement, by RAW.

Comment: @mcv That's how it would have been IRL, as far as I understand it, anyway. But if the players and GM don't enjoy the crunchy bits of horses, you could always house-rule the feed for a party of adventurers (the horses graze while you make camp). Though, in all honesty, in a Kingmaker campaign I'd keep the feed rules to test your (as a King) understanding and grasp of logistics. :P

Comment: @Jason_c_o Who *doesn't* enjoy the crunchy bits of horses? Those are the best parts!

Comment: Well, the horses weren't much good in the forests anyway. @HeyICanChan It was another campaign where we had to eat our horses. They weren't much good in a jungle either. Horses are primarily good when you need to move fast over short distances in open terrain. Or pull a cart.

Comment: @mcv: donkeys and mules are the superior cart-puller.  They aren't prone to panic and can be trained to be willing to enter caves or other underground areas.  Horses can't.

Comment: @Jeff True. Oxen are also popular as cart-pullers, though I'm not sure what their advantages and disadvantages are. I suspect they're slow and cheap.